Extension of two analytic functions in multiple variables
Suppose we have two functions, holomorphic in multiple variables, given by
$$f_j: \mathbb{C}^{n + 1} \setminus \{z_j = 0\} \to \mathbb{C},\quad f_k: \mathbb{C}^{n + 1} \setminus \{z_k = 0\} \to \mathbb{C},$$
where $1 \leq j < k \leq n + 1$. Also, assume both $f_j, f_k$ agree on the intersection $\mathbb{C}^{n + 1} \setminus \{z_j \cdot z_k = 0\}$. Does there exist an entire function $F: \mathbb{C}^{n + 1} \to \mathbb{C}$ that extends both $f_j$ and $f_k$?
For context, this came up in my fiber bundles course in the proof of the statement that the space of global holomorphic sections of a line bundle over $\mathbb{C} P^n$ is isomorphic to the space of complex polynomials in $n + 1$ variables that are homogeneous of degree $k$.
I apologize if this is a trivial question, I know next to nothing about the theory of analytic functions in multiple variables.

@MoisheKohan No I think this solves my question. Thanks for your comment.
